# How to add padding between TitledPanes in an Accordion in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-2, accordion

I would like to add padding between `TitledPane`s in an `Accordion` (spacing in `Accordion`).

The problem is that, when a `TitledPane` is expanded, the look and feel of the next `TitledPane` is broken.

`TitledPane`s unexpanded

[image]

One `TitledPane` expanded

[image]

*I have used the following CSS:*

```
.titled-pane {
    -fx-skin: "com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TitledPaneSkin";    
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-base-color;
    -fx-padding: 0.5em;
}
```

One image show the separation between 2 `TitledPane`s unexpanded, and another image show the look an feel of the second `TitledPane` after open the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug (I've created a bug report: [JDK-8162599](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8162599)).

As a workaround, if you specify only the **bottom padding** of `TitledPane`s (rather than the top), the spacing between `TitledPane`s in the `Accordion` is correct.

*CSS to add bottom padding*

```
.accordion > .titled-pane {
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0.5em 0;
}
```

*An example `Accordion` looks like this:*

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It fixed my issue.